# Mule ESB: How to use rules in DataMapper for condition checking

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Please help me. I'm using datamapper to convert xml to csv. PF my xml below. If ID = 1, then i need to map schoolRating , and also  ID=2 then need to map schoolRating with other filed in csv. Though this xml i created schema.

```
<root>
  <schoolTypes>
    <ID>1</ID>
     <Record>
       <SchoolRating>4.0</SchoolRating>
       <Tables>67</Tables>
     </Record>
  </schoolTypes>
  <schoolTypes>
   <ID>2</ID>
     <Record>
       <SchoolRating>3.0</SchoolRating>
        <Tables>67</Tables>
     </Record>
   </schoolTypes>
 </root>
```

i have tried to create rules like this in DataMapper, but it throws error.

```
     Context:  /ns0:root
     Xpath:    /ns0:schoolTypes/@(ns0:ID='1')/ns0:Record/ns0:SchoolRating
```

Also tried with multiple options but no hope. Please let me know the right syntax for this condition or any other approach to handle this in DataMapper. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create the rule in DataMapper:

```
Context:  /ns0:root
Xpath:    /ns0:schoolTypes[ns0:ID='1']/ns0:Record/ns0:SchoolRating
```

you may need to check [this](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/using_conditional_statement_in_xpath_rule_using_datamapper) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Link really helped me a lot. i got to know multiple condition check.